Looking for a sci-fi movie where two mad scientists keep a live head connected with wires to machines
About ten years ago (2010s), I watched a sci-fi film about two insane scientists who kept a living head in a laboratory. The head belonged to another scientist buddy of the first two, and it was connected to various machines via a series of wires and connections. I'm not certain, but I believe one of the scientists was played by actor Peter Stormare, but I might be confusing it with his role as Dr. Solomon Eddie in Minority Report (2002). I also think I remember that the scientists were killing people in order to obtain the ideal body for their bodyless companion. This ends up being the body of the hero (Who I don't remember either) attempting to flee from the insane scientists.
None of the following films/TV movies is the one that I am looking for:

The Brain That Wouldn't Die (1962)

The Brain of Morbius. Doctor Who S13E19 (1976)

The Man with Two Brains (1983)

Cold Lazarus. British TV miniseries (1996)

X-Files: I want to believe (2008)

RoboCop (2014)

Body Parts (1991)

They Saved Hitler's Brain (1968)

Zaveshchaniye professora Douelya (1984)

The Frozen Dead (1966)

The Head (1959)


The movie was in color and in English. I've been looking for Stormare's roles on imdb, but I haven't found the movie.

Hmmm... I don't see any matches in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LosingYourHead

The close film I've found is "X-Files: I want to believe" but I am sure it is not, even though it is also about a severed human head alive. I will re-check Stormare's early Swedish films just in case.

Is it the whole head, or just the brain?

@ArlettaS - It is the whole severed head.

DId the technology in the film's lab look modern (computers, etc.), or more like something from the 50s/60s?

@E.Z.Hart - Mostly, it looked like 60s/70s (oscilloscopes and rheostats).

A partial match would be "The Head": Dr. Abel keeps the severed head of his colleague, Dr. Ood, alive through experimental surgery. The head is connected to various machines and wires, and Dr. Abel and his assistant kill people to find the perfect body for Dr. Ood. But it's black and white:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Pg-RXMKUEg

There's a colorized version of "The Head" with an English dub, which would make it a closer match (though still missing some details): https://archive.org/details/the-head-colorized-movie-720p-hd

I'm guessing not Body Parts https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101492/

Also not They Saved Hitler's Brain https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0265870/

@ParkerMacInnis - Neither Body nor Hitler is the movie that I watched. Thank you.

Just for the whole list: Professor Dowell's Testament

@YaroslavKornachevskyi - Thank you for bringing in that interesting film that I have never seen.

@Bingo - You've yet to rule out The Head (1959), as brought up by Peter several days ago. It's the closest match to your description so far, although it's rather old to be a film you thought Peter Stormare might've been in.

Probably also worth ruling out The Frozen Dead (1966).

Dr. Donovan, please call your office.

Not to get a head of myself, but there's always Cold Lazarus

Some of this matches the story of the 1985 film Re-Animator (based on the HP Lovecraft story), and I may be getting parts of the story mixed up with what went into the film. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089885
